# MIPS Psuedo Random Pattern Generator

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a homework problem for a Computer Architecture course that requires me to program a basic PRPG.

The basic concept, as I understand it, is to take some starting number and call it the seed. From there, you square the seed and store it as a 32 bit word. Then, you drop bits 8 through 23, combine bits 0-7 and 24-31, and sign extend it. Store it back, increment the memory counter, and loop until you have as many numbers as you want.

My question is concerning the "dropping" of the middle bits, following the combination of the remaining bits. How exactly would one go about this? I was thinking of doing a logic or bit shift but I'm not really sure how that would work.

Answer (score 1):

You need shifting and masking to do that.

In C, it would be written

```
int new, old;
int mask=0x000000ff ; // 
new =   (old & mask)            // keeps  only LS byte of old
      | ((old >> 16) & ~mask) ; // and add MSByte at position 8:15
```

You only need instructions AND, OR, NOR (to complement mask), and shifts.
Better use SRA instead of SRL for right shift, as you have for free sign extension.